# How to query MongoDB using WithinCircle and another term?

Tags: mongodb, grails, groovy, criteria

How can I query MongoDB for a geospatial location and another term (e.g., a tag or category)? I tried the following criteria

```
searchResults = Company.withCriteria {
    withinCircle( [50d,8.5d], 60  )
    inList('tags', tagName)
}
```

but it looks like "withinCircle" is not implemented for criterias. Is there another technique? Using the dynamic finder "findAllBy...And..." did also not work:

```
Company.findAllByTagsAndLocationWithinCircle( tagName, [ [50d, 8.5d], 60 ] )
```

(Both give me a "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method..." error.)

Do I miss something or is there a way via the low-level API (gmongo) etc.?

The domain classes look like:

```
class Company {
    ObjectId     id
    Set          tags     = []                      // a set of ObjectID referencing Tags
    List<String> tagList  = new ArrayList<String>() // a list of names from the Tags
}

class Tags {
    ObjectId     id
    Set          companies = []                    // a set of ObjectID referencing Companies
}
```

BtW: Company.tags and Company.tagList are in-sync and only used for testing (I started with tags but thought tagList could help in the search)

Comment: Shouldn't the criteria have `withinCircle('location', [[50d,8.5d],60])`?

Comment: Yes - using just "withinCircle" works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

```
class Company {
    ObjectId id
    List location

    static hasMany = [tags: Tag]

    static mapping = {
        location geoIndex:true
    }
    .....
    //static mapWith = 'mongo' //if required
}

class Tags {
    ObjectId id
    String name
    .......
    //static mapWith = 'mongo' //if required
}
```

Based on the above domain classes the below criteria will give you what is needed. Rectify if the mapping is correct and what you need.

AFAIK `inList` is not used in criteria. You can try with the below criteria:

```
searchResults = Company.withCriteria {
    withinCircle('location', [[50d,8.5d], 60])
    tags{
       eq('name', tagName)
    }
}
```

Taking into consideration my comment above on `withinCircle` and assuming `tagName` is a list.

(*Untested) Alternatively, using a dynamic query it would be

```
def companies = Company.findAllByLocationWithinCircle([[50d, 8.5d], 60]).findAll{
    tagName in it.tags*.name   
}
```

If `withinCircle` does not go hand in hand with combination of dynamic finder then it can be broken as well (which may be resource consuming).

Comment: Thanks, using withinCircle alone works but I also need the select objects that are tagged with at least one tag (in my example tagName is not a list but one tag - e.g., "Grails" and the objects have a Set of tags they are related to (i.e., a one-to-many relationship))

Comment: @JörgRech Well in that case you have to use an association. See my update above. Can you also show the Company domain class which will make things clear for me. I assumed `name` is the part of `Tag`.

Comment: The dynamic query "Company.findAllByLocationWithinCircleAndTagsInList([[50d, 8.5d], 60], tag.name)" or "Company.findAllByLocationWithinCircleAndTagsInList([[50d, 8.5d], 60], [tag.name])" does not work

Comment: @JörgRech Yes, that is why I asked for the domain classes `Company` and `Tag` to be added to the question. Can you add them based on which a valid inference can be derived. :)

Comment: I found one variant to search the tags using findAll (but withinCircle does not work there :-():
    searchResults = Company.findAll {
        inList('tagList', tag.name)
    }

Comment: This is basically what I have for the domain objects but I get an UnsupportedOperationException: "Join queries are not supported by MongoDB" when I use the criteria (btw. I only use mongodb and not a hybrid with hibernate).